# Entire function mapping $f(a_{n})=b_{n}$ for $a_{n}\to \infty$ distinct and $b_{n}$ arbitrary sequence

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem: Find entire function mapping $f(a_{n})=b_{n}$ for distinct sequence  $a_{n}\to \infty$ and arbitrary sequence $b_{n}$.

I was hoping for a simple construction, but here is mine (if it works)

Assume $a_{0}=0$

$f(z)=z\cdot \sum_{n\geq 1}b_{n}\cdot [\prod_{m\neq n}|\frac{z-a_{m}}{a_n-a_{m}}|e^{-\sum^{m} \frac{1}{k}\frac{z^{k}}{a_{m}^{k}}+\sum^{m} \frac{1}{k}\frac{a_{n}^{k}}{a_{m}^{k}}}] \cdot e^{-|b_{n}F_{n}(z)||z-a_{n}|^{2}}+b_{0},$

where $F_{n}(z)$ is the weierstrass product inside the bracket.

Any much much simpler constructions?

Comment: I don't think there's a very easy method. The usual argument is to use Mittag-Leffler to produce poles at the $a_j$ with the correct residues and multiply by a Weierstrass product.